Unpack tar made with tape-length option gives Illegal byte sequence
I had some big MP4 files that I wanted to backup to Amazon S3. Uploading them in the web interface gave me some timeouts so I created 4GB tar files using:
tar -cv --tape-length=4G --file=backup-{000..999}.tar /mnt/videofiles/

Now stupid me of course didn't test the extraction and now, when I finally needed to restore a backup, I run into an error for every mp4 that is bigger than 4GB and thus stretched over multiple tars:
tr: Illegal byte sequence
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...
tar: Damaged tar archive
tar: Retrying...

I tried unpacking with GNU tarcat, but that gives the same error.
tarcat.sh ../backup*.tar | tar tf -
tarcat.sh ../backup*.tar | tar xzvf -

Did I mess up badly? How can I fix this?

i see xzvf .. is it gzipped ?

Try to combine the files first: cat backup-{000..999}.tar > combined-backup.tar and then try igonre failures: tar -xvf combined-backup.tar --ignore-zeros --ignore-failed-read , let’s see if you can recover something

Not zipped I think, since I used "tar -cv --tape-length=4G"

Then why pass z along as option ? Just use xvf then.

@Silbee only tar xvf doesn't make a difference

@TowsifAhamedLabib on OSX the tar command doesn't support the ignore options, I now install homebrew gtar which does support them. Unfortunately it still fails.
VID_20240412_102113.mp4
gtar: Skipping to next header
._VID_20240412_102113.mp4

I just don't understand that there is the option to define "--tape-length=4G" but you can't seem to glue them back together...... or have I made a big mistake in using this option?

tar --help | less .... -M, --multi-volume         create/list/extract multi-volume archive might not be of any help now... try?  What does $ file backup* say about the files? Any specifics about which format they are in?

The multi-volume option should be triggered automatically when I used --tape-length, according to: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Multi_002dVolume-Archives.html#Multi_002dVolume-Archives

file backup* says:
POSIX tar archive (GNU)
tar archive
tar archive

Suspected: sigh no working unit test on that, nobody uses it so not noted.

Sorry, I don't fully understand your response :-) Might be because I'm not native-english speaker. Are you saying it might be some bug that was never noticed because this feature is hardly ever used?
Would you have a suggestion on how to combine large files and split them in future for my other backups?

Sorry, I suspect that tar has a bug regarding handling multi-archives.

$ tar --version - might be interesting, for both versions of tar (the one used for creating the backup, and the one used for extraction attempts)

I went back to my laptop and checked the history log. I've created the tar files on my laptop with gtar:
gtar --version gives tar(GNU tar) 1.35
So I used gtar like this:
gtar -cv --tape-length=4G --file=......... etc. etc....

The manual says it comes with tarcat link but I couldn't find tarcat and then downloaded it from here: link.
I tried extracting with tar and gtat like this:
tarcat video-000.tar video-001.tar video-002.tar video-003.tar video-004.tar video-005.tar video-006.tar video-007.tar video-008.tar video-009.tar video-010.tar video-011.tar video-012.tar | gtar xf -
But always get the tr: Illegal byte sequence gtar: Skipping to next header

SOLVED IT !!!
I was using the wrong command to untar the multi volume tar. This is the solution, point to the first tar file of the range:
gtar -xMf video-000.tar

Then wait for the unpack and it will ask for the next volume. Now give the name of the next volume and put the letter n in front (don't know why):
n video-001.tar
n video-002.tar
etc

Now to find a scripted way to do this ;-)
